# Performance Factor in Generating Excel via Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are generating the an excel workbook based on a template that looks like:

[image]

...from a source file that looks like:

```
filename1   1:1Of1:39   accountNum1                                 C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  C   12345,00    EUR 230424  C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   1:2Of2:39   accountNum2 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   2:2Of2:39   accountNum2 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   1:11Of3:39  accountNum3 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   2:11Of3:39  accountNum4 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   3:11Of3:39  accountNum4 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   4:11Of3:39  accountNum4 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424                  
filename1   5:11Of3:39  accountNum4 0000    230424  ABC 20230424000000000   12345,00    D   AB-23-00000000  Ref/    C   12345,00    EUR 230424                  D   12345,00    EUR 230424  D   12345,00    EUR 230424
```

using this:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ZDMT940FlatToExcel {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ZDMT940FlatToExcel.class);
    private static final String authorName = "Self";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.info("Direct Invocation!");
        ZDMT940FlatToExcel ma_1 = new ZDMT940FlatToExcel();
        String bankName = "ABC";
        String inFileName = "C:\\target\\output.txt";
        String outFileName = "C:\\target\\EBS_" + bankName + ".xlsx";
        System.out.println(ma_1.generateMT940Excel(bankName, inFileName, outFileName));

    }

    public String generateMT940Excel(String bankName, String inFileName, String outFileName) {

        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        String _timeNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
        String MT940Text = readFileIntoSting(inFileName);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

        try {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(
                    ZDMT940FlatToExcel.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("EBS_Result_Template.xlsx"));
            wb.getProperties().getCoreProperties().setCreator(authorName);
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(printStackTraceToString("generateMT940Excel", "", e));
            return "NOK";
        }

        XSSFSheet templateSheet = wb.getSheet("##BankName##");

        CellStyle borderStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
//      borderStyle.setWrapText(true); //disabled owing to its mess-up with predefined column width
        setCellStyleAllBorders(borderStyle);

        int baseRowForTransactions = 6;
        XSSFSheet clonedSheet = wb.cloneSheet(wb.getSheetIndex(templateSheet), bankName);
        clonedSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue(templateSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).toString()
                .replace("##BankName##", bankName).replace("##EBSType##", "MT940"));
        clonedSheet.getRow(2).getCell(3)
                .setCellValue(templateSheet.getRow(2).getCell(3).toString().replace("##TimeStamp##", _timeNow));
        int _tableSize = MT940Text.split("\r\n").length;

        for (int j = 0; j < _tableSize; j++) {
            int _rowNum = baseRowForTransactions + j;
            Row _rowInCxt = clonedSheet.createRow(_rowNum);
            String _transactionInCtx = MT940Text.split("\r\n")[j];
            String[] _transactionInCtxSize = _transactionInCtx.split("\t");
            for (int k = 0; k < _transactionInCtxSize.length; k++) { //borders missing if empty appear as last columns, yet to fix
                Cell _cellInCxt = _rowInCxt.createCell(k);
                String _valueInCtx = _transactionInCtxSize[k];
                _cellInCxt.setCellStyle(borderStyle);               
                _cellInCxt.setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx, " "));
//              _cellInCxt.getCell(k, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx));               //using alternate approach                      
            }
        }
        clonedSheet.setColumnHidden(0, true);
        clonedSheet.setColumnHidden(1, true);

        wb.removeSheetAt(wb.getSheetIndex(templateSheet));

        try {
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(printStackTraceToString("generateMT940Excel", "", e));
            return "NOK";
        }
        log.info("Written xlsx file");
        return "OK";
    }

    private static void setCellStyleAllBorders(CellStyle cellStyle) {
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    }

    private static String readFileIntoSting(final String fileName) {
        byte[] data = null;
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            data = fin.readAllBytes();
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(printStackTraceToString("readFileIntoSting", "", e));
            return null;
        }
        return new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private static String nvl(String text, String defaultValue) {
        if (text == null || text == "") {
            return (defaultValue == null) ? " " : defaultValue;
        }
        return text;
    }

    private static String printStackTraceToString(String callerId, String addRem, Exception e) {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return callerId + ":\t" + addRem + ":\t"
                + errors.toString().trim().replaceAll("\r\n", " ").replaceAll("\t", " ");
    }

}
```

While the code does its job, the performance factor is unsatisfying. The source tab delimited text file contains about 10k lines and it already takes about 5 minutes. Could the code be made more efficient to improve performance? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the following block:

```java
int _tableSize = MT940Text.split("\r\n").length;
        for (int j = 0; j < _tableSize; j++) {
            int _rowNum = baseRowForTransactions + j;
            Row _rowInCxt = clonedSheet.createRow(_rowNum);
            String _transactionInCtx = MT940Text.split("\r\n")[j];
            String[] _transactionInCtxSize = _transactionInCtx.split("\t");
            for (int k = 0; k < _transactionInCtxSize.length; k++) { //borders missing if empty appear as last columns, yet to fix
                Cell _cellInCxt = _rowInCxt.createCell(k);
                String _valueInCtx = _transactionInCtxSize[k];
                _cellInCxt.setCellStyle(borderStyle);               
                _cellInCxt.setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx, " "));
//              _cellInCxt.getCell(k, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx));               //using alternate approach                      
            }
        }
```

to this:

```java
int[] j = { 0 };
        Stream<String> MT940Texts = MT940Text.lines();
        MT940Texts.forEach(l -> {
            int _rowNum = baseRowForTransactions + j[0];
            Row _rowInCxt = clonedSheet.createRow(_rowNum);
            String[] _transactionInCtxSize = l.split("\t");
            for (int k = 0; k < _transactionInCtxSize.length; k++) {
                Cell _cellInCxt = _rowInCxt.createCell(k);
                String _valueInCtx = _transactionInCtxSize[k];
                _cellInCxt.setCellStyle(borderStyle);
                _cellInCxt.setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx, " "));
//                  _rowInCxt.getCell(k, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellValue(nvl(_valueInCtx, " "));               //using alternate approach                      
            }
            j[0]++;
        });
```

made a tremendous difference. It now takes only 6 seconds to generate the output.